# Javascript OnChange not firing on first change

Tags: javascript, html

I have an issue concerning an 'onchange' event within a select html element. The code i have written is supposed to display certain text boxes depending on which select option has been selected.

The code I have is as follows:

```
Customer Type: 
<select name="customerType" onchange="cust_type()">
<option value="" selected>Customer Type?</option>
<option value="nonCorp">Customer</option>
<option value="corp">Corporate</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
function cust_type() {  
   var select_drop = document.getElementsByName('customerType');
   var selected = select_drop[0].value;
   var f_name = document.getElementById('forename');
   var s_name = document.getElementById('surname');
   var c_name = document.getElementById('companyName');

   if(selected == "") {     
     f_name.style.visibility = 'hidden';
     s_name.style.visibility = 'hidden';
     c_name.style.visibility = 'hidden';            
     f_name.value = "";
     s_name.value = "";
     c_name.value = ""; 
   }    
   if(selected == "nonCorp") {      
         f_name.style.visibility = 'visible';
         s_name.style.visibility = 'visible';
     c_name.style.visibility = 'hidden';        
     c_name.value = ""; 
   }    
   if(selected == "corp") {     
     f_name.style.visibility = 'hidden';
     s_name.style.visibility = 'hidden';
     c_name.style.visibility = 'visible';       
     f_name.value = "";
     s_name.value = ""; 
   }
}
```

The problem I am experiencing is that when I change the option in the select menu the first time, the onchange has no effect. However on the second, third etc etc it seems to be working perfectly fine.

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: On the initial change, are you actually changing the value from what it was initially?

Comment: Where's the rest of your onchange event? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: Yes. For example I would change it from "Customer type?" to "Customer" or "Corporate" @DanielJohnson

Comment: What do you mean @the_pete

Comment: Did you try something like that : yourSelectElement.onchange = cust_type;

Comment: Disregard, I missed it.

Comment: No @user3384518, could you elaborate?

Comment: In fact, I prefer declare JS event from the JS, not directly in the html code. So, if you can JUST try to add an ID like id="test" to your  select and, in your JS code just after having declare cust_type, add document.getElementById('test').onchange = cust_type; (Your JS Code must be load after the page was loaded)

Comment: Hi @queval_j, I tried this but it has not solved the problem.

Comment: What does the code for your text boxes look like currently? Your `onchange()` event is firing properly so the problem isn't there.

Comment: where is the **forename** , **surname** and **CampanyName** in your HTML code ?

Comment: it's in my answer @Alaeddine

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the event in JavaScript ?

```
var yourSelectElement = document.getElementById('test');
yourSelectElement.onchange = cust_type;
```

Let see : http://jsfiddle.net/YtuxP/

Do you try to do that ?

Comment: No I didn't. I've solved the problem now, I'm just about to post the fix. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Fix:

Instead of directly changing the visibility of the text boxes I wrapped them in separate divs. The code solution is as follows.

HTML:

```
Customer Type: 
<select name="customerType" onchange="cust_type()">
<option value="" selected>Customer Type?</option>
<option value="nonCorp">Customer</option>
<option value="corp">Corporate</option>
</select>   

<div id="nonCorpCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="visibility:hidden">

    Forename <input type="text" name="forename" id="forename" onchange="submit_check()" />
Surname <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" onchange="submit_check()" /.

</div>

<div id="corporateCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="visibility:hidden">

Company Name <input type="text" name="companyName" id="companyName" onchange="submit_check()" />

</div>
```

JS function:

```
function cust_type() {

var select_drop = document.getElementsByName('customerType');
var selected = select_drop[0].value;
var f_name = document.getElementById('forename');
var s_name = document.getElementById('surname');
var c_name = document.getElementById('companyName');
var nonCorp = document.getElementById('nonCorpCustDetails');
var corp = document.getElementById('corporateCustDetails');


if(selected == "") {

        nonCorp.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    corp.style.visibility = 'hidden';

    f_name.value = "";
        s_name.value = "";
    c_name.value = "";

}

if(selected == "nonCorp") {

    nonCorp.style.visibility = 'visible';
    corp.style.visibility = 'hidden';

    c_name.value = "";

}

if(selected == "corp") {

    nonCorp.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        corp.style.visibility = 'visible';

    f_name.value = "";
    s_name.value = "";

}


}
```